# Pandas: Replace NaN Using Random Sampling of Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, `df`, containing several columns.  Some of the values in `df` are `NaN`.  I want to replace each `NaN` with a valid value, chosen by randomly sampling from other values in the given column.

For instance, if:

`df[work] = [4, 7, NaN, 4]`

I'd like to replace `df[work][2]` with 4 2/3 of the time and 7 1/3 of the time.

Here's my attempt:

```
def resample_fillna(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        # get series consisting of non-NaN values
        valid_series = df[col].dropna()
        nan_indices = np.argwhere(np.isnan(df[col]))
        for nan_index in nan_indices:
            df[col][nan_index] = valid_series.sample(n=1)
```

I'm thinking there's a much better, more Pythonic way.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you to replace all the missing values with the same random value or a different random value for each?

Comment: This transformer does that automatically: https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_doc/imputation/RandomSampleImputer.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's create some fake data and then fill the missing values with random other values from the same column.

```
np.random.seed(123)
data = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10,5))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('abcde'))
df = df.where(df > 2)
df

     a    b    c    d    e
0  NaN  NaN  6.0  NaN  3.0
1  9.0  6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  9.0  NaN  NaN  9.0  3.0
3  4.0  NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN
4  7.0  3.0  NaN  4.0  7.0
5  NaN  4.0  8.0  NaN  7.0
6  9.0  3.0  4.0  6.0  NaN
7  5.0  6.0  NaN  NaN  8.0
8  3.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  6.0
9  NaN  4.0  4.0  6.0  3.0
```

Now we can loop through each column with `apply` and sample with replacement from the non-missing values.

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.isnull(), x.dropna().sample(len(x), replace=True), x))

     a    b    c    d    e
0  5.0  3.0  6.0  6.0  3.0
1  9.0  6.0  4.0  9.0  7.0
2  9.0  5.0  8.0  9.0  3.0
3  4.0  3.0  8.0  4.0  6.0
4  7.0  3.0  4.0  4.0  7.0
5  9.0  4.0  8.0  6.0  7.0
6  9.0  3.0  4.0  6.0  3.0
7  5.0  6.0  4.0  4.0  8.0
8  3.0  5.0  4.0  4.0  6.0
9  9.0  4.0  4.0  6.0  3.0
```

Comment: Why do you use `len(x)` within `sample` instead of just doing `n=1`?

Comment: @bclayman if you sample n = 1.  This will pull one value from your set and place one value in all the NaN instead of sampling the set one time for each nan.  For example in the given setup by Ted, the first column would get the same value for all three NaN if you did n=1 instead of n=len(x).